# embedded tomcat setenv configuration with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I want to provide the contents of setenv when running a spring boot app on an embedded tomcat container. What is the best place to do this?

I would like it to be in an external file and also ensure that tomcat is able to access it before the spring context loading kicks in.